# android: string arrays (copy all or select from another string array with criteria)

Tags: android, arrays, string

## Situation:

I have a string array in the resource, which consists of all types of, say, questions.

If user clicks for All types, for example, to select all, then the `selection_question` string array would copy all the items in `all_question`.

Yet if user clicks for a specific type of questions, say, to select just animal related questions, then the `selection_question` string array would copy all the items in `all_question` that contains "animals" this word.

My code is as simple as follows:

**declare:**

```
String[] all_Question ;
String[] selection_Question;
```

**OnCreate:**

```
all_Question = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.all_Q_List); 
all_numberofquestions = all_Question.length;

// reset 
selection_numberofquestions = 0;
selection_Question = new String[0];
j =0;
```

**if to select all:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < all_numberofquestions ; i++) 
{
    selection_Question[i] = all_Question [i];
}
```

**if to select based on some criteria:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < all_numberofquestions ; i++) 
{
    if (all_Question [i].contains("animal"))
    {
        selection_Question [j] = all_Question [i];
        j++;
    }
}
```

## Question:

It then popups with the following error as shown in Logcat:

```
03-04 22:14:10.568: E/AndroidRuntime(24917): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

I does not understand why it is Out of Bounds? How could the above codes be modified?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem.

`selection_Question = new String[0];`

It should have been

`selection_Question = new String[all_numberofquestions];`

Or even your `all_question` could be `blank/empty`.

Comment: I would like to know whether this will then affect the size of the selection_Question? this is because if just to select using criteria, then the size of the selection_Question would be smaller than all_question, and then those remaining slot at the back would it be affected?

Comment: I mean is it possible to create a string ready to start from nothing and when there are new items just keep to add in and expands... but not to reserve at first place...or does it matter actually? (ps: i have checked all_question is not blank, it contains 400 items, and i have checked all_question[0] it shows the string, so as [100]. [200])

Comment: Sounds like you want an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Comment: @pearmak - As `Geobits` mentioned, you should look into `ArrayList`. Will reduce quite a lot of your work.